# How can I get a TF feature column from a dataframe column?

Tags: python, tensorflow, feature-extraction

I have a dataframe:

[image]
I want to create a feature column out of the integer "length" column of this dataframe. How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 0):

```
featcols = [
    tf.feature_column.numeric_column("length")
]
```

This is a [reference.](https://colab.research.google.com/notebooks/mlcc/first_steps_with_tensor_flow.ipynb?hl=en#scrollTo=RKZ9zNcHJtwc)